# How to use DLLs with dependencies at install AND uninstall time in Inno Setup?

Tags: dll, inno-setup, pascalscript

I want to import two dlls in my .iss when uninstalled the app. I cannot find a way to do this.

```pascal
procedure Installed();
external 'Installed@files:StatisticInstallInfo.dll,adcore.dll cdecl  setuponly ';

procedure Uninstalled();
external 'Uninstalled@{app}\StatisticInstallInfo.dll cdecl  uninstallonly';
```

I want import `adcore.dll` in procedure `Uninstalled` too. And it's failed as below shows;

```
[Files]
Source: {#MyDefaultPackDir}\adcore.dll; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: {#MyDefaultPackDir}\StatisticInstallInfo.dll; DestDir: "{app}"
```

```pascal
[Code]
procedure Uninstalled();
external 'Uninstalled@files:StatisticInstallInfo.dll,adcore.dll cdecl  uninstallonly';
```

It does not work.

`Installed()` and `Uninstalled()` are in the `StatisticInstallInfo.dll`, which depends on `adcore.dll`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the installer is running, Inno has access to the contents of the setup, and so can extract any files needed using the `files:file1.dll,file2.dll` syntax.

At uninstall time, Inno no longer as access to the contents of the setup so it needs to rely on anything you extracted at install time using a normal `[Files]` entry. Because of this, it no longer cares about the dependencies and leaves that up to you.

```
[Files]
Source: "StatisticInstallInfo.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "adcore.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"

[Code]
procedure Installed();
external 'Installed@files:StatisticInstallInfo.dll,adcore.dll cdecl setuponly';

procedure Uninstalled();
external 'Uninstalled@{app}\StatisticInstallInfo.dll cdecl uninstallonly';
```

Depending on when you call that function (if after the install itself) you can scrap the `files:...` syntax and just use `{app}\StatisticInstallInfo.dll` in both cases.

Comment: what you mean is that I use {app}\StatisticInstallInfo.dll. and it auto call the function in adcore.dll?

Comment: Yes, that is handled by your `StatisticInstallInfo.dll` at both install and uninstall time. The `files:a.dll,b.dll` just causes both to be extracted, nothing more. Installing them both to `{app}` does the same thing, it just makes sure they are both extracted to use.

Comment: You may need the [`loadwithalteredsearchpath` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptdll&anchor=loadwithalteredsearchpath). See [Loading DLL with dependencies in Inno Setup fails in uninstaller with “Cannot import DLL”, but works in the installer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65018560/850848)